# Why do I get this error installing MySQL server?

Tags: debian, mysql

So I have a empty VPS running Debian 7 32bit. The VPS has just been created so nothing is installed but the base OS.

I run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install mysql-server` and i get this error:

```
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst: line 146: logger: command not found
ATTENTION: An error has occured. More info is in the syslog!
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst: line 236: logger: command not found
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up heirloom-mailx (12.5-2+deb7u1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx to provide /usr/bin/mailx (mailx) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.91-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@linux:~#
```

Any idea what's going on and how can I get MySQL server working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is since logger is not correctly installed and reinstalling bsdutils should solve this

```
apt-get --reinstall install bsdutils
```

[here is the same problem on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506243/mysql-strange-installations-problems-logger-command-not-found)

Comment: Yes, works perfectly after this. Thanks. It's weird that this is not setup as a dependency for mysql-server package.